# Turning an object with arrays as properties into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I go about turning

```
{
  "service": [["A"],["B"]],
  "cost":[[20],[50]]
}
```

into

```
[
  {service:"A", cost:20},
  {service:"B", cost:50}
]
```

I don't even know where to start honestly...

Comment: array reduce is where to start - though, data being in `[["A"],["B"]]` format seems odd, could be just `["A","B"]` unless there's the possibility of `[["A", "C"],["B"]]`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, I'll see what I can do with reduce and go from there! Yes, the reason for the structure is how my useState from React Hooks is building the services. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You can use either for/in loops, or map/reduce. Point being there are essentially 2 problems. 1. Iterate over service values to create objects 2. iterate over cost values assign and to corresponding objects.

Comment: is the assumption that the count of service values is the same as the count of cost values?

Comment: Hey @HariLubovac, yes that's how's the useState hook builds it (or at least how I've managed it). There will always be one service for one cost, added at the same time

Comment: Then, Iguess, you can loop through one od those arrays, and locate matching values in the other array by index, and then assemble the resulting object however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your object around to get your desired result, first, transform your object to the following using `.map()` with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
[
  [
    {
      "service": "A"
    },
    {
      "service": "B"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "cost": 20
    },
    {
      "cost": 50
    }
  ]
]
```

Next, zip these two inner arrays together (the first element of the first array gets grouped with the first element of the second array, the second element of the first array gets grouped with the second element of the second array), using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as the grouping method:

```js
const obj = {"service":[["A"],["B"]],"cost":[[20],[50]]};
const [first, ...r] = Object.entries(obj).map(([k,vals]) => vals.map(([v]) => ({[k]: v})));
const zipped = first.map((o, i) => Object.assign(o, ...r.map(arr => arr[i])));

console.log(zipped);
```

We can take a similar approach using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const obj = {"service":[["A"],["B"]],"cost":[[20],[50]]};
const [first, ...r] = Object.entries(obj).map(
  ([k,vals]) => vals.map(([v]) => [k, v])
);
const zipped = first.map((entry, i) => Object.fromEntries(
  [entry, ...r.map(arr => arr[i])]
));
console.log(zipped);
```

Comment: I will study this closely Nick, thank you! I need to work on my understanding of data structures. More practice is well due. Thank you again!

Comment: @realhat no worries. The syntax can be a little daunting if you're not used to it. Here are some links [destructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) that might help. If you have any additional questions about the syntax let me know

Comment: It's interesting, because I do work with spread and destructuring regularly with React, but I clearly don't have a deep understanding of them. I will seek out some resources where I can practices more complicated problems :) Looking at how you answered this problem, I'm sure with my current knowledge I wouldn't have gotten there. Or at least, not as elegantly or as quickly. Which tells me I need to work on my problem solving...