# How can I create several arrays on each of the values of other array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

So currently I have this array structure:

```
const object = {
  object1: ["01", "02"],
  object2: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
  object3: ["product1", "product2"]
}
```

and I need to transform it to:

```
const array = [
  {
    object1: "01",
    object2: "item1",
    object3: "product1",
  }, {
    object1: "02",
    object2: "item1",
    object3: "product1",
  }, {
    object1: "01",
    object2: "item2",
    object3: "product1",
  }, {
    object1: "01",
    object2: "item3",
    object3: "product1",
  }, {
    object1: "02",
    object2: "item2",
    object3: "product1",
  }, {
    object1: "02",
    object2: "item3",
    object3: "product1",
  }, {
    object1: "01",
    object2: "item1",
    object3: "product2",
  }, {
    object1: "02",
    object2: "item1",
    object3: "product2",
  }, {
    object1: "02",
    object2: "item2",
    object3: "product2",
  }, {
    object1: "03",
    object2: "item2",
    object3: "product2",
  },
]
```

So basically I need to create a new array based off of each combination on the initial object of arrays, and the initial array the be on the thousands of items.

This is what I have so far but no luck getting the structure I need.

```
const object = {
  object1: ["01", "02"],
  object2: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
  object3: ["product1", "product2"]
}
const arr = []
Object.entries(object).forEach((element, i) => {
  element.forEach((innerElement, j) => {
    let _element = {[`${element[0]}`]:element[1][j]}
    arr.push(_element)
  })
});

console.log("map", arr)
```

Is there any way to transform the data to the structure I need it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help? Structure is almost the same as yours: [Turning an object with arrays as properties into an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60461297)

Comment: Hey @NickParsons, I just tried it and changed it a bit but it's only returning 2 objects out of the initial data I mentioned. What it's doing is generating a new object based off its position, like this:

```
0: Object
object1: "01"
object2: "item1"
object3: "product1"
1: Object
object1: "02"
object2: "item2"
object3: "product2"
```

and that's not really what I need. I'm trying changing it but it's a bit hard.

Comment: Oh I see, yes, you're after multiple combinations so it's not the same type of question. I think the below answers should help you out though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a generic solution that will iterate over the possible properties and values of the template `object` and create an array of all possible outcomes.

We'd create a `addPossibleValues()` function than will expand the array of objects for each key in the template object. Each round will increase the number of objects by the successive length of the relevant property array.

```js
const object = {
  object1: ["01", "02"],
  object2: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
  object3: ["product1", "product2"]
}

function addPossibleValues(arr, property, possibleValues) {
    return possibleValues.flatMap(v => { 
        return (arr.length ? arr: [{}]).map(x => { 
            return { ...x, [property]: v};
        })
    });
}

let result = [];
for(let key in object) {
    result = addPossibleValues(result, key, object[key]);
}

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could also do this using a [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call:

```js
const object = {
  object1: ["01", "02"],
  object2: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
  object3: ["product1", "product2"]
}

function addPossibleValues(arr, property, possibleValues) {
    return possibleValues.flatMap(v => { 
        return (arr.length ? arr: [{}]).map(x => { 
            return { ...x, [property]: v};
        })
    });
}

let result = Object.keys(object).reduce((acc, key) => {
    return addPossibleValues(acc, key, object[key]);
}, []);
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Idea**

Step-wise generation of the cross product of the arrays in the original object:

- Iterate through all of the original object properties.
- Consider some iteration.
- Assume that we have an interim array filled in the previous iterations
- For each of the values `cv` of the array stored as the current iteration's property `cp` in the original object ...

  - take each object from the interim result array
  - clone it
  - add a property `cp` to the cloned object nd fill it with the value `cv`.
  - add the clone to the result array
- conclude the iteration by removing the originals of the coning operation from the result array (these are now obsolete as they arethe cross product of one dimension less).
- Initialize the while procedure with an array with a single empty object

**Code**

```js
const object = {
  object1: ["01", "02"],
  object2: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
  object3: ["product1", "product2"]
}


let a_res = [{}];
for (s_key in object) {
    let n_currentCount = a_res.length
      ;
          
    object[s_key].forEach ( ps_item => {
        for (let i = 0; i < n_currentCount; i++) {
            let o_new = Object.assign({ [s_key]: ps_item }, a_res[i])
              ;
              
            a_res.push(o_new);
        }
    });

    a_res.splice(0, n_currentCount); // in situ
}
console.log(a_res);
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks for the insight @collapsar!

Answer (score 1):

First, I must apologize about my English. You could use 3 nested forEach.

```js
const object = {
  object1: ["01", "02"],
  object2: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
  object3: ["product1", "product2"]
}

var arr = []

object.object3.forEach(o3 => 
  object.object2.forEach(o2 =>
    object.object1.forEach(o1 => 
      arr.push({object1: o1, object2: o2, object3: o3}))));
      
console.log(arr);
```

Change the order of the forEach if you prefer to change the order of the combinations

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that the dimension of the cross product and the property names must be known beforehand. On the pro side it is the simplest approach ...

Comment: That's right, the object can have as many properties as possible, so, as mentioned, this is the simplest approach but not the best in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, collapsar approach is better. I also think that for a learning point of view, the best is first understand my approach because is very simple and specific. And once my approach is totally understood, understand collapsar approach becase its a very elegant solution.